# BitmapImage не работает с Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf

Интересная ситуация, при попытке установки значения для `BitmapImage.UriSource` через привязку данных, вот так:

```
<catel:UserControl x:Class="Watch.Views.SerialPreviewView"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                   xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"
                   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                   mc:Ignorable="d"
                   d:DesignWidth="200" d:DesignHeight="300" MaxWidth="200" MaxHeight="300" Margin="2.5">

    <Border Background="WhiteSmoke" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="21" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="21" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Row="1">
                <Image MinHeight="300" MinWidth="200">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage CacheOption="OnDemand" CreateOptions="DelayCreation"
                                     UriSource="{Binding SerialInfo.PreviewImage, TargetNullValue='https://dummyimage.com/200x300/cecece/000000.png'}" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="3">
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding SerialInfo.TranslatedTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           ToolTip="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="3">
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding SerialInfo.OriginalTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           ToolTip="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </Border>

        </Grid>
    </Border>

</catel:UserControl>
```

После инициализации `View` происходит исключение:

> InvalidOperationException: Необходимо задать свойство "UriSource" или
>   "StreamSource".

Т.е. в момент инициализации `DataContext` еще не установлен, но это произойдет немного позже. Как с этим бороться т.к. игнорируется значение `TargetNullValue` а так же `FallbackValue`?

Comment: Устанавливать `DataContext` через xaml ?

Comment: @NewView: нет, он автоматически подставляется фреймворком `Catel`.

Comment: ммм.. а если все же прописать? Я так понимаю что потом его можно и изменить, в том числе из фреймворка. Вопрос кажется в том чтоб оно было доступно в момент инициализации.

Comment: Посмотрите я же написал что даже при установленном `TargetNullValue` это значение не подставляется. Других способов это сделать нет.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает что инитить `TargetNullValue` нужно локальным значением.. что то типа картинки в ресурсах..

Comment: Вам нужно именно `FallbackValue`, а не `TargetNullValue`. TargetNullValue — это когда привязка есть, но в источнике лежит null, а FallbackValue — это когда привязка сломана или в ней вообще какое-то недопустимое значение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите (c).

`TargetNullValue` предназначен для случаев, когда привязка работает, но источник содержит значение `null`, у вас же, пока `DataContext` не установлен, привязка оказывается в нерабочем состоянии, но для `BitmapImage` это недопустимо, он обязательно должен иметь установленное свойство `UriSource` или `StreamSource`.

Для случаев, когда привязка сломана или источник содержит недопустимое значение предназначена именно фича `FallbackValue`, т. е. вроде бы ваш пример должен заработать если написать так:

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Uri, FallbackValue='https://dummyimage.com/200x300/cecece/000000.png'}"/>
```

Но он не заработает как нам нужно: заглушка для картинки появится, но когда мы установим `DataContext`, она не поменяется на нужную нам. Тут есть еще одна загвоздка (читайте [комментарии в статье про `BitmapImage` на MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=netframework-4.7.2#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)):

> ... После инициализации изменения свойств игнорируются.

т. е. созданное единожды `BitmapImage` навсегда останется таким.

Тут у вас есть несколько вариантов:

- написать простой конвертер, который будет по строке (или Uri) создавать новый экземпляр `BitmapImage`:

  ```
  class UriToBitmapImageConverter : ConverterBase
  {
      public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
          var b = new BitmapImage
          {
              CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand,
              CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation
          };
          b.BeginInit();
          b.UriSource = new Uri((string)value);
          b.EndInit();
          return b;
      }
  }
  ```

  и воспользоваться им:

  ```
  <Image Source="{Binding Uri, Converter={c:UriToBitmapImageConverter},
      FallbackValue='https://dummyimage.com/200x300/cecece/000000.png'}"/>
  ```
- воспользоваться фичей `PriorityBinding`:

  ```
  <Window.Resources>
      <BitmapImage x:Key="Placeholder" UriSource="https://dummyimage.com/200x300/cecece/000000.png"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  ```

  затем:

  ```
  <Image>
      <Image.Source>
          <PriorityBinding>
              <Binding Path="Uri" IsAsync="True"/>
              <Binding Source="{StaticResource Placeholder}"/>
          </PriorityBinding>
      </Image.Source>
  </Image>
  ```

  но здесь, конечно, `BitmapImage` создается автоматически с настройками по умолчанию.

В обоих вариантах получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересная штука `PriorityBinding`. Не знал об этом классе.