# BitmapImage игнорирует StreamSource

Tags: c#, wpf

Я не совсем понимаю, почему когда устанавливаю `StreamSource` для `BitmapImage`, он всегда будет `null`.

Сделал небольшой конвертер `Uri` изображений с локальным кэшированием, с использованием `IsolatedStorageFile`. При запросе изображения идет перенаправление запроса к локалбному хранилищу, и при отсутствии кэша, грузится из сети, при этом после загрузки сразу же кэшируется.

Но как только я пытаюсь установить `StreamSource` для `BitmapImage`, он просто при возврате `BitmapImage` будет всегда `null`, да и само изображение не загружено.

```
string fullPath = BasePath + "\\" + filePath + ".cache";

if (!Iso.FileExists(fullPath))
{
    return null;
}

BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage
{
    StreamSource = Iso.OpenFile(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
};

return result;
```

Возможно ли это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В этом коде очевидно ошибок нет. Если null в StreamSource, то нужно смотреть `Iso.OpenFile`. Выложи его код.

Comment: Не совсем понял что вы хотите увидеть. [Вот это?](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.openfile?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Надо сначала `BeginInit()`, потом указываем источник (UriSource, StreamSource или т.п.), потом `EndInit()`. До `BeginInit` и после `EndInit` изменения свойств игнорируются. См. также: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/922868/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасли меня, напишите ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание, класс `BitmapImage` реализует интерфейс `ISupportInitialize`. Это значит, что он поддерживает "пакетную инициализацию", т. е. вы должны вызвать у объекта `BeginInit`, затем установить нужные свойства (`UriSource` или `StreamSource` и другие параметры) и вызвать `EndInit`. Все установки свойств до `BeginInit` и после `EndInit` игнорируются. Другой способ инициализации — вызов параметризированного конструктора, но в наличии есть только конструктор с `Uri`.